# Symfony collection forms - Save to json_array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Hove to create collections of field and store in one db column type json_array?

My entity have column date_data which is json_array type. I want to render two fields on frontent.

First Field -> from - date type. 
Second Field -> to - date type.

I use jQuery repeater lib, for render this fields as repeater field on frontend. And want to store fields data from repeater in date_data column in db like this.

`[{"from": '12/31/2009' , "to": '01/16/2010' }, {"from": '02/10/2011' , "to": '02/16/2011' }]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create entity with `json` column for your data:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestRepository")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private $data;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getData(): ?array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData(?array $data): self
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and 2 forms: first for entity and second for data collection item:

App\Form\Test

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as FormType;

class Test extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('data', FormType\CollectionType::class, [
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'entry_type' => 'App\\Form\\Data',
                'label' => 'Data',
            ])
            ->add('save', FormType\SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Save',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'App\\Entity\\Test',
        ]);
    }
}
```

App\Form\Data

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as FormType;

class Data extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('from', FormType\TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'from',
            ])
            ->add('to', FormType\TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'to',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    }
}
```

And in controller

```
    $test = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Test')->find(1);

    $form = $this->createForm(\App\Form\Test::class, $test, []);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump($form->getData());
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Tnx. I think it works. But I do not know how to render form in .twix. I use `{{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_row(form) }}
                <ul>
                    {% for fields in form.data %}
                        <li>
                            {{ form_errors(fields) }}
                            {{ form_widget(fields) }}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {{ form_end(form) }}` and I don't see fields in browser.

Comment: you can render whole form `{{ form(form) }}`

Comment: I know, but in dom i se <form> tag and other things. But i can't se fields in folection. from and to fields

Comment: try `<li> {{ form_errors(fields) }}     {{ form_errors(fields.from) }}
    {{ form_widget(fields.from) }}     {{ form_errors(fields.to) }}
    {{ form_widget(fields.to) }} </li>`

Comment: Don't work. Render lable and div with data-prototype attr filled with some html code. And render submit button but no fields from collection

Comment: Seems data field is emty. Try to set some test value. Ex.: `[{"to": "01/16/2010", "from": "12/31/2009"}, {"to": "02/16/2011", "from": "02/10/2011"}]`. Also clean doctrine metadata cache `php ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: Works! Tnx a lot!